# How to manipulate DOM elements inside a TemplateRef without using pure javascript

Tags: angular6

I have this template in my Component class

```
    <ng-template #thumbnailTemplate>
      <div> <!-- top level div of thumbnail. This will have ids thumbnail-1, thumbnail-2 etc.-->
        <img> <!-- this will have width, height=80-->
        <a></a> <!-- the X button is created using CSS. This will have ids close-button-1, close-button-2. They'll also containn reference to the parent div id (thumbnail-1, thumbnail-2 ) -->
      </div>
    </ng-template>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="custom-file" id="file-upload" lang="es">
        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="question-file-upload" formControlName="image" [ngClass]="validateField('image')" (change)="handleFileSelect($event)" required>
        <label class="custom-file-label" for="question-file-upload">
          Select file...
        </label>
      </div>


      <div id="image-thumbnail-container">
        <ng-container #thumbnailContainer ></ng-container> <!-- This will contain the view created from #thumbnailTemplate. It can have multiple thumbnails. Check .ts file-->
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the use selects an image file from `input` element, I want to show a thumbnail of the image. I am able to do this using pure javascript code (`createElement`, `setAttribute`, `addEventListener` etc.) but I suppose I shouldn't mix `JS` code in `Angular`. So I plan to use `ViewChild`, `Renderer2`, `ViewContainer` and `TemplateRef`).

So far, I have got to the point where I have got reference of the template and the view container.

```
@ViewChild("thumbnailContainer",{read:ViewContainerRef}) thumbnailContainerRef:ViewContainerRef;
  @ViewChild("thumbnailTemplate",{read:TemplateRef}) thumbnailTemplateRef:TemplateRef<null>;
  @ViewChild("image-thumbnail-container",{read:ElementRef}) imageThumbnailContainer:ElementRef;
```

But I don't know how to get access to the `div`, `img` and `a` inside the template? As a user can select multiple files, the `ViewContainer` can have multiple `Views` of the `TemplateRef`. So I want to give the `div` and `a` different `ids` and also set the `src` of the `img. I suppose I can use`Renderer2`APIs to set the attributes but for that I need to pass`nativeElement`of the`div`,`img`and`a`to it. But I don't know how to get`nativeElement` of these as they are inside a template.

Comment: can't you place them and change their behaviour with ngIf?

Comment: sorry, I didnt understand what mean. I want that if I place the template at 3 places then for each instance of the template, I provide different values of `src` attribute of `img`. I don't know how `ngIf` would help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to delete a specific view from viewcontainer angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51764692/how-to-delete-a-specific-view-from-viewcontainer-angular)